# Community dedicated to music transcriptions

Tags: transcription, musescore

Do you happen to know any e-community related to music transcription? Many times I have doubts about parts of my transcriptions and it would be nice to seek others' opinion.

Comment: Requesting off site resources is off topic.

Answer (score 1):

Transcriptions are derivatives of original recordings and the vast majority of "interesting" original recordings not played from score sheets (which would then have a copyright situation separate from the recording) would likely be still copyrighted as well.

So most such "e-communities" would likely be barred by copyright legislation from operating in a reasonably open manner.

Comment: That's too bad because it would be really cool to have a website that crowd sourced transcription help and checks of ones work. How do sites like ultimate-guitar post tab versions of those songs? Wouldn't the tab have the same issues. Or could it be because they're so bad they aren't close enough to the recording ;)

Comment: @b3ko - you mean they're supposed to represent the song in their title..?

Comment: @b3ko Ultimate Guitar has licensing agreements with music publishers but sometimes they are forced to remove certain songs at the request of the artists. Many sites have been shutdown though. In the early 2000s Powertab and MySongBook both had some legal issues and did not have such agreements. Many tabs migrated to Ultimate Guitar, which if I recall correctly, was operating out of Russia at the time so the legality was a bit more complicated.